# php namespace clashes with dompdf and AWS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, namespaces, dompdf

We have existing stuff in our code base that uses dompdf (version 0.5.1)... which has no namespace.

When I include the the aws.phar, using something like

```
require '/path/to/aws.phar';
```

all of sudden, I get fatal errors

```
Class 'DOMPDF' not found in XXXX on line 1193
```

The code that is causing the error is simply a new instantiating of the class:

```
$dompdf = new \DOMPDF();
```

I am guessing this is a namespace problem, but I have no idea how to go about fixing it, since I already put the global escape in front of DOMPDF... If I comment out the require line for the phar, then everything goes back to working.

I also did open up the AWS.phar to see what is going on inside.  From the code that is not obfuscated, I see that they are using the symfony class loder.

```
$classLoader = new Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader();
$classLoader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Aws'      => 'phar://aws.phar/src',
    'Guzzle'   => 'phar://aws.phar/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src',
    'Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher' => 'phar://aws.phar/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher',
    'Doctrine\\Common' => 'phar://aws.phar/vendor/doctrine/common/lib',
    'Psr\\Log' => 'phar://aws.phar/vendor/psr/log',
    'Monolog'  => 'phar://aws.phar/vendor/monolog/monolog/src'
));
```

I tried a couple of different things also to register the dompdf with the class loader, but they all threw errors.  I am guessing bc it if written without namespaces.

I have also tried loading the dompdf include config file before and after loading the phar, it seem to make no difference.

Anyone have any suggestions??

Comment: Which version of dompdf are you using? Are you including the dompdf config file before or after including aws.phar? v0.5.x doesn't uses a less compatible autoloader than 0.6.0.

Comment: we are using v0.5.1.  I have tried including the config both before and after the aws.phar, seems to have made no difference.  I don't understand your sentence " v0.5.x doesn't uses a less compatible autoloader than 0.6.0." Do you mean "does use a less compatible autoloader" ?

Comment: Where is the source code for that version of DOMPDF?

Comment: @HerbGirl ha ha, yes, should be "v0.5.x uses a less compatible autolaoder" ... though that's still a bit awkward.

Comment: @JeremyLindblom FYI, you can find the 0.5.x source here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/v0.5.2. But I think just using that release is the problem.

Comment: Yeah, `__autoload()` is garbage. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

v0.5.1 of dompdf did not yet implement SPL autoloading, it registered `__autoload()`. This outdated method of autoloading didn't work very well because it was difficult to register more than one autoload function at a time. Plus, when using writing PHP that *does* use SPL autoloading the v0.5.1 autoloader will not be called. PHP SPL autoloading disables calling `__autoload()` ([spl_autoload_register](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)).

v0.6.0 ([just released](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases)) uses SPL autoloading and should be compatible with AWS.phar. v0.6.0 is (for the most part) a drop-in replacement for v0.5.1 so you might want to try upgrading your copy of dompdf.

If that's not possible for whatever reason you could register the dompdf autoloader manually using SPL after including dompdf_config.inc.php. At a minimum you could try the following:

```
<?php
require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
spl_autoload_register('DOMDPF_autoload');
// ...
?>
```

See the [dompdf v0.6.0 autoload include](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/v0.6.0/include/autoload.inc.php) for a more complete example.